# When building composite controls and using session, can they conflict with host application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, session

I wrote a composite web control that is used in several web applications. If I use sessions variables, for example `HttpContext.Current.Session("MyProgramMemberId")`, do I run the risk that the host site might have also defined that same session key name?

I'd like to hear of your experiences if you had a problem with this. It would be a bonus if you have website reference that you trust.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that I have any actual experience with this (mainly because I wouldn't do this), but yes it's *absolutely* possible that you could have a collision with another session variable named the same thing in the hosting web application.

What I would suggest is removing the reliance on the session variable, and instead use a [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) variable instead.  These are more isolated to specific instances of your control, and therefore should not conflict with each other.  Of course there are considerations based on what you need to store, you would want to be careful trying to store large objects, lists, dictionaries, as well as sensitive information in the viewstate (which ends up being transmitted to the client).  But based on your sample code, it looks like it's a simple Id property which is small and (usually) not sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! This is why StackOverflow is awesome

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on how you setup your website. If you are re-using the control in different web applications but on the same site it should not be an issue. If you are re-using them in the same application this would be a design issue.

If you are asking if you need to be worried if your session names will collide if you go to a shared host you will not need to worry. The thing you will have to worry about is if you are storing your session InProc. If you are storing your values InProc and your site is load balanced there could be issues as the balancer chooses different servers to serve your content.